# jquery validation change error message on dropdown change

Tags: jquery, validation, drop-down-menu

I'm new to jquery, i'm using validation plugin from http://bassistance.de, so far is working fine, until certain page i need to change the error message on dropdown change, instead of submit button clicked.

Here is what i have in my error message part

> messages: {

```
   txtLocation: {

     required: function(){ 
                    if($("select[name=selDelBasis] option:selected").text()=="C&F FIFO" || $("select[name=selDelBasis] option:selected").text()=="CIF FIFO")
                        return "Please enter the name of discharge port.";
                    else
                        return "Please enter the name of port from where you will load your coal.";
            }},
```

In my html i have a select with name=selDelBasis and an input type text name="txtLocation"

To populate the problem here is the step.
1. Choose C&F FIFO from selDelBasis dropdown
2. Click Submit, without filling the txtLocation
3. Error message appear as "Please enter the name of discharge port."
4. Change selDelBasis from "C&F FIFO" to "FAS"
5. The error message no changes, still same "Please enter the name of discharge port."

What i want is on step 5, the error message should change to "Please enter the name of port from where you will load your coal."

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i managed to found a solution on this question.
I used one of the validation method which is showErrors().

So in my dropdown onchange event, i do this

`validator.showErrors({"txtLocation": "Please enter the name of discharge port."});`

while validator is
`var validator = $("#frmMarket").validate();`

Thanks for all help, i hope this thread can help other that have the same question

Comment: Make sure you don't forget to accept your answer as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well, but I guess that set `onclick` option would do what you want:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onclick: false
})
```

Analogously there is also `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` options:

A complete list of options:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions